# Syntax error in update when using where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm stuck in an `update` query. I'm working on registration form where if confirm mail link is been redirected to site then update query pass and update row with confirm value.

Here is the error message:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''users' SET 'confirm'='1' WHERE
>   'com_code'='732aabcb4ad6a03b51e0a55aab998726'' at line 1

Please check where my syntax is wrong:

```
UPDATE 'users' 
SET 'confirm'='1' 
WHERE 'com_code'='732aabcb4ad6a03b51e0a55aab998726';
```

Thanks!

Comment: Single quotes are for string literals, not identifiers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to put `confirm`, `users` and `com_code` inside quotes, 
use this:

```
UPDATE users 
SET confirm ='1' 
WHERE com_code='732aabcb4ad6a03b51e0a55aab998726';
```

Answer (score 4):

To quote identifiers use backticks ` [Identifier Names](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/identifier-names/)

> Identifiers may be quoted using the **backtick character** - `. Quoting is
>   optional for identifiers that don't contain special characters, or is
>   a reserved word. If the ANSI_QUOTES SQL_MODE flag is set, double
>   quotes (") can also be used to quote identifiers.

```
UPDATE `users` 
SET `confirm`='1' 
WHERE `com_code`='732aabcb4ad6a03b51e0a55aab998726';
```

or don't use them at all if your identifiers aren't keywords or don't contains spaces and so on:

```
UPDATE users 
SET confirm ='1' 
WHERE com_code='732aabcb4ad6a03b51e0a55aab998726';
```

Comment: Thanks @lad2025  , its working. please explain where i am wrong

Comment: @JaswinderKaur 'user' is string literal and UPDATE statements wants identifier